# How could an app be hacked if using just authentication in MERN app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm creating a MERN full stack app and trying to get my head around authorization and authentication. If I was just to include authentication on the login page (ie. a function that checks if the user and password provided matches that of the database) and then allow the user access to all of their information (let's say blog posts) and all of CRUD operations, could somebody give me a hypothetical example of how a hacker could access or perform some of these operations without authorization being imposed?

Comment: Hmmm if you don't authorize your user, what's the point of authenticating? Authorization involves the process of validating a session cookie or jwt token before allowing a user to use an unsafe HTTP verb on an endpoint or allowing access to a page. Having authentication but not imposing authorization is like issuing a temporary key to someone to access your house but you always leave the house door open...

Answer (score 2):

After having successfully authenticated the first request (`POST /login`, say), how do you plan to authenticate the subsequent CRUD requests (`GET /myaccountbalance`, say)? You write "then allow the user access to all ...", but how do you plan to do that?

A well-established mechanism is to establish a *session* for the user on the server after login and send a session cookie back to the browser, which will then include that session cookie in all subsequent requests. Your server need only validate that a session exists before executing a CRUD request. The cookie thus acts like a session-specific password, and hackers definitively cannot obtain it via cross-site scripting if the cookie is [httpOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies). But perhaps you knew that already.

Session handling in express is easy with [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I've been reading a bit about JWTs, which I think do the same as session cookies.

In your example, I would use `GET /myaccountbalance/:id` with the id being the user.id that is obtained when the user logs in. So how could a hacker get hold of that id to make the request? I would do a similar thing for a `PUT` and `DELETE` request, this time having `posts/:id`, with the id being post.id.

Comment: The hacker can sniff the network traffic of a hacked user's computer to see where http requests are going.

Comment: JWTs must be handled in Javascript, whereas httpOnly session cookies are hidden from Javascript. Also, you should not include the user.id in the URL, because that can be manipulated. The user.id must  be derived in the backend from the session.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples, not all of which are completely preventable:

- User passwords might be guessable, or already leaked. This is why you have to enforce some complexity requirements, and maybe check against known leaked passwords from this API: https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3
- If you don't have a rate limiting / suspicious activity detection mechanism, logins might be brute-forced
- Depending on how your code is written, you might have forgot to check authentication on certain routes
- CSRF https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf
- Assuming you hash passwords, the login view might be subject to timing attacks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack)

If you weren't using MongoDB, SQL injections would also be a thing to concider.